# cannot convert type System.Collections.Generic.Icollection<int> to int

Tags: c#, icollection

I want to obtain all the possible ways to make a certain price using four basic denominations (1,5,10,25). I have the following code. I know it generates the results in a collection but I don’t know how to extract the integers at runtime. Can someone help?

```
void CoinCalculator()
{
    //function that checks how many coins and of what denomation the player needs

    //get a copy of the purse contents
    priceChecker = ApplicationManager.am_keyPrice;  //hold key Price


    List<ICollection<int>> coins = new List<ICollection<int>> ();


    coins.Add(CoinChange1.GetCoinSets(priceChecker)[0]);


}

public class CoinChange1
{
    private int[] cs = new [] {25, 10, 5, 1};

    private List<ICollection<int>> solutions = new List<ICollection<int>> ();

    public static IList<ICollection<int>> GetCoinSets(int total) {
        // Handle corner case outside of recursive solution
        if (total == 0)
            return new List<ICollection<int>> ();

        // Get all possible sets
        CoinChange1 cc = new CoinChange1 ();
        cc.GetCoinSets (total, 0, new Stack<int>());
        return cc.solutions;
    }

    private void GetCoinSets(int n, int csi, Stack<int> combo) {
        // Find largest allowable coin (exploiting that cs is ordered descendingly)
        while (cs[csi] > n)
            csi++;
        int c = cs [csi];

        combo.Push (c); // Track coin selection
        if (n == c)
            solutions.Add(combo.ToArray()); // Base case
        else
            GetCoinSets (n - c, csi, combo); // Recursion 1: with a selected coin
        combo.Pop ();

        // Recurse for all other possibilities beyond this point with a combo of smaller coin units
        if(csi < (cs.Length - 1))
            GetCoinSets (n, csi + 1, combo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Easy, don't use ICollection<T> because it sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a list of collections so to output them to the console for example:

```
foreach(ICollection<int> coll in solutions)(
{
     foreach(int item in coll)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(item);
     }
}
```

Because you have alist of collections you must iterate the list and for each item in the list iterate the collection to get to your int.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the result and "print" them or do whatever you want. For instance.

```
        var result = GetCoinSets(priceChecker );            
        // display result
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++) {
            string valuesSeparatedByComma = string.Join(", ", result[i]);

            Debug.WriteLine($"Combinaison #{i + 1}: {valuesSeparatedByComma}");
        }
```

would display if you enter **15**:

```
Combinaison #1: 5, 10
Combinaison #2: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10
Combinaison #3: 5, 5, 5
Combinaison #4: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5
Combinaison #5: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5
Combinaison #6: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added the following line to pass to an array and it worked...   int[] coins = CoinChange1.GetCoinSets (priceChecker) [0].ToArray<int> ();

Comment: Casting a List<int> to an Array of int (int[]) is really that useful, they both can be iterated the same way.